# Unknown color java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-activity, colors

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color

```
    String lsGray = "#333";
    tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(lsGray));
```

Answer (score 2):

Full Color Hex Code

```
 String lsGray = "#333333";
 tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(lsGray));
```